# Does iterating over returned data call the function every time in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
def some_function():
    # do something
    return iterable_data

for datum in some_function():
    # do something
```

Here `iterable_data` may be a list, a dictionary, etc.

So, does the for-loop calls `some_function()` every time it looks up the next element of the returned `iterable_data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the expression list is executed *just once*. From the [`for` compound statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> The expression list is **evaluated once**; it should yield an iterable object. An iterator is created for the result of the `expression_list`. The suite is then executed once for each item provided by the iterator, in the order of ascending indices.

Emphasis mine.

You can easily test this yourself:

```
>>> def some_function():
...     print "some_function called"
...     return ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
... 
>>> for datum in some_function():
...     print datum
... 
some_function called
foo
bar
baz
```

The `"some_function called"` text is printed just once, not three times.

Answer (score 1):

```
def some_function():
    # do something
    print 'the function has been called'
    return [1,2,3]

for datum in some_function():
    print datum



>>the function has been called
>>1
>>2
>>3
```

so only one time